# Login Password -Iniciar sesión BBDD MySQL - PHP

Tags: php, html

Estoy realizando una página inicial de **verificación de usuarios**, con sus respectivas contraseñas. Esta información la extraigo de una tabla de la base de datos **MySQL**. He realizado la conexión a la base de datos correctamente, y a la hora de realizar la conexión o probar el fichero "**index.php**" me da el siguiente error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$sql' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\cabañas\index.php on line 8
```

Os adjunto el código de **index.php:**

```
<?php
    //Crea una sesión para ser usada mediante una petición GET o POST.
    session_start();
    include_once "conexion.php";

    //Función para comprobar el login del usuario.
    function verificar_login($usuario, $password, &$result){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM administradores WHERE usuario = '$usuario' and password = '$password'";
        $rec = mysql_query($sql);
        $count = 0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rec)){
            $count++;
            $result = $row;
        }
        if($count == 1){
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    //Si exise la sesión...
    if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario_id'])){
        //Si fue pulsado el botón "Login"...
        if(isset($_POST['login'])){
            if(verificar_login($_POST['usuario'], $_POST['password'], $result) == 1){
                $_SESSION['usuario_id'] = $result->idusuario;
                header("location:index.php");
            } else {
                echo '<div class="error">Su usuario es incorrecto. Inténtelo nuevamente.</div>';
            }
        }
?>

        <form action="" method="POST" class="login">
            <div><label>Usuario: </label><input name="usuario" type="text"></div>
            <div><label>Password: </label><input name="password" type="password"></div>
            <div><input name="login" type="submit" value="login"></div>
        </form>

<?php
    } else {
        echo 'El usuario '.$usuario.' ingresó correctamente.';
        echo '<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>';
    }
?>
```

Adjunto el código de **conexion.php:**

```
<?php
    //Datos para la conexión a MySQL.
    define('db_server','localhost');
    define('db_name','osmarrural');
    define('db_user','root');
    define('db_pass','');
    $con = mysql_connect(db_server, db_user, db_pass);
    mysql_select_db(db_name, $con);
?>
```

PD: Estoy con Notepad++.

¿Alguna solución?

Comment: Es posible que tengas que utilizar la función `mysqli`, `mysql_fetch_object`ya no se utiliza. Añade una i y prueba.

Comment: Parece que te falta una llave o paréntesis cerca de la línea `$sql = "SELECT * FROM administradores WHERE usuario = '$usuario' and password = '$password'";` Estás seguro que este es tu código de script `index.php` ??

Comment: Si, ese es mi código index.php

Comment: Definitivamente, no creo que cambiar la librería mysql por mysqli (que es un excelente consejo) solucione un error de parser.

Comment: Prueba de la siguiente manera:
"SELECT * FROM administradores WHERE usuario = ".$usuario."and password =" .$password; Lo mas recomendado es usar PDO y usar las "Prepare Statements" ya que podrías sufrir de un ataque de inyección SQL.

Comment: Lo he probado y nada, todo sigue igual.

Comment: Pregunta editada con el código de conexion.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He cambiado la conexión de **mysql** a **mysqli** ya que es una versión mejorada de mysql y ofrece mejor rendimiento, el código quedo asi:

**conexion.php**

```
<?php
    //Datos para la conexión a MySQL.
    define('db_server', 'localhost');
    define('db_name', 'osmarrural');
    define('db_user', 'root');
    define('db_pass', '');
    $con = mysqli_connect(db_server, db_user, db_pass, db_name);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        die("Error al conectarse al servidor y/o base de datos: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php session_start(); //Crea una sesión para ser usada mediante una petición GET o POST.
    include_once "conexion.php";

    //Función para comprobar el login del usuario.
    function verificar_login($con, $usuario, $password, &$result)
    {
        $count = 0;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM administradores WHERE usuario='".$usuario."' and password='".$password."'";
        if($rec = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
        {
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($rec);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($rec))
            {
                $result = $row;
            }
            /* liberar el conjunto de resultados */
            mysqli_free_result($rec);
        }
        /* cerrar la conexión */
        mysqli_close($con);

        return $count;
    }

    //Si exise la sesión...
    if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario_id']))
    {
        //Si fue pulsado el botón "Login"...
        if(isset($_POST['login']))
        {
            //Sanear variables
            $usuario =  trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, filter_input(INPUT_POST, "usuario", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
            $password =  trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, filter_input(INPUT_POST, "password", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));

            if(verificar_login($con, $usuario, $password, $result) == 1)
            {
                $_SESSION['usuario_id'] = $result->idusuario;
                $_SESSION['usuario_nombre'] = $result->usuario;
                header("location:index.php");
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<div class="error">Su usuario es incorrecto. Inténtelo nuevamente.</div>';
            }
        }
    ?>
        <form action="index.php" method="POST" class="login">
            <div><label>Usuario: </label><input name="usuario" type="text"></div>
            <div><label>Password: </label><input name="password" type="password"></div>
            <div><input name="login" type="submit" value="login"></div>
        </form>

    <?php
    }
    else
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['usuario_nombre']))
        {
            echo 'El usuario '.$_SESSION['usuario_nombre'].' ingresó correctamente.';
        }
        echo '<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>';
    }
    ?>
```

!Espero te sea de ayuda!

Comment: Funciona. Aunque hay una cosa que quiero retocar ya que no funciona del todo correctamente pero creo que se debe a la configuración del config.inic.php